# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure in a quartz job in Spring webapp + the SP does not give consistent results

Tags: java, stored-procedures, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring webapp which is basically a monitoring application. There are various KPIs defined in the appliation and I am using Quartz framework to make these KPIs run at regular intervals. One of the Quartz Job calls an Oracle Stored Procedure (with one input and one output parameter). I am using JDBC Callable Statement to call the SP from job. The Stored Procedure is so written that it returns 0 in case of any exception.

The issue that i am facing is that the call from JAVA to this stored procedure is not giving consistent results. Sometimes, the procdeure returns correct results and sometimes it results 0. However if I run the SP directly in SQLDeveloper then it runs perfectly fine.

I have debugged quite a lot on this but didnt find anything. Is it something related to snchronous/asynchronous running of SP or is it some issue with the connection object used to excute the SP. I simply need some pointers which I can use to continue my debugging.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your problem is about the Stored Procedure, I would reword the whole question to focus on the body of the stored procedure, how you execute it and the expected results against the current result. Note that the problem is about Oracle and Java rather than Spring, Quartz or whatever other technology you're using.

Answer (score 0):

just a 2 cents suggestion. Instead of returning 0 in case of any error, why not returning the real code of error (sign negative)?

Exemple, ORA-01401 would just return -1401.

This way, you will be able to identify the real reason of errors (and if it comes from server or client side).

Regards.
Christian (I'm french, sorry for my frenchglish ;-) )

Comment: Actually the return of 0 is not specifically an ORA error...It can be a non existing business scenario also